# How to sharing GeoMap Based Push Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, geomap

I have developed an application that shows one's location on a map. How do I go about sharing my current location with others who are using my application? Is it possible to send them a notification to let them know my current location.

Comment: Have you tried anything.If yes then plz show so that we may help you solve errors.But no here is going to write whole code for you.

Comment: Actually i did not get what should i do first . if you give some idea than i will start .
i did the get location and address using gps , now what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're aiming for, but you're probably gonna need some server side job to handle things to you (besides the code from your app and the Google Cloud Message). You could use some mBAS to facilitate your job. [Parse](http://www.parse.com) is a good one, but there are others available.

You sure as hell have to get your hands dirty and start to code something. It's hard to help with a question so vague.